# What does $\phi^{(n)}(t)$ mean for a portfolio?

Tags: portfolio

I am currently in the process of deciphering the notes written by an instructor. I missed the class.

He writes:

> Continuous time trading: $S(T) = W(T)$, "Bachelier Model". $\phi(t)$
>   denotes number of shares held at time t. Approximation is
>   $\phi^{(n)}(t) = \phi(t_i), t_i < t < t_{i+1}, t_i = \frac{i}{n}T$.
>   Gain from strategy $\phi^{(n)}$ is $\sum_{i=1}^n \phi(t_{i-1})[W_{t_i}
> > - W_{t_i -1}] = \int_0^T \phi^{(n)}(s) dW(s).$

I don't understand what $n$ or $\phi^{(n)}$ is. Is it a derivative?

Answer (score 1):

n is the number of time steps used in the discrete time solution $\phi^{(n)}$ to approximate the continuous time solution $\phi$ (the time period $T$ is being broken up into n steps). The higher the n the better the approximation. In the expression $\phi^{(n)}$ n is a super-script, not an exponent nor a derivative.

I have a feeling that later on you are going to be told that $n \rightarrow \infty $ ...